# How to add Firefox Bookmarks (from Windows) to Ubuntu Firefox bookmarks

Tags: firefox, backup

I want to move my Windows 8.1 Firefox bookmarks over to Ubuntu 17.04 Firefox.

So I went to `C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles` 
and found the bookmarks backups in the `jsonlz4` format.

I've also read [this article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-bookmarks-from-backup-or-move-them#w_moving-bookmarks-to-another-computer)

But it says that to restore bookmarks from a backup I'd have to lose the bookmarks I already have on my Ubuntu Firefox.

Is there a way to import my Windows Firefox bookmarks to Ubuntu's Firefox without losing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Is there a way to merge the bookmarks on my old pc to those on my new
>   pc?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1021828)

---

> Unfortunately, Firefox does not have good tools for merging and
>   de-duplicating bookmarks. I'm going to suggest a round-about way to do
>   this. Here's a general overview:
>
> 1. Create a new blank profile (profile #3) in your current Firefox (see details at the end)
> 2. While using profile #3, restore a JSON-format backup file from your old system (profile #1) (see Restore bookmarks from backup or move
>      them to another computer)
> 3. Export the restored bookmarks to an HTML format in a convenient location, with a unique file name (see Export Firefox bookmarks to an
>      HTML file to back up or transfer bookmarks)
> 4. Exit Firefox and start up again in your normal profile (profile #2)
> 5. Import the HTML-format bookmarks file (see Import Bookmarks from an HTML file)
> 6. Create a backup in case anything goes wrong in step 7 (see Restore bookmarks from backup or move them to another computer)
> 7. Reorganize the bookmarks from the Imported Bookmarks folder (see https://support.mozilla.org/kb/use-bookmarks-to-save-and-organize-w...),
>      possibly using a deduplicating add-on
>
> Create a new Firefox profile
>
> A new profile will have your system-installed plugins (e.g., Flash)
>   and extensions (e.g., security suite toolbars), but no themes, other
>   extensions, or other customizations. It also should have completely
>   fresh settings databases and a fresh cache folder.
>
> Exit Firefox and start up in the Profile Manager using Start > search
>   box (or Run):
>
> ```
> firefox -P
> ```
>
> Do not delete anything here. Any time you want to switch profiles,
>   exit Firefox and return to this dialog.
>
> Click the Create Profile button, assign a name like OldBookmarks, and
>   skip the option to change the folder. Then start Firefox in the new
>   profile you created.
>
> You're ready to restore to this new profile and create the HTML-format
>   export.
>
> When returning to the Profile Manager, you might be tempted to use the
>   Delete Profile button. But... it's a bit too easy to accidentally
>   delete your "real" profile, so I recommend resisting the temptation.
>   If you do want to clean up later, I suggest making a backup of all
>   your profiles first in case something were to go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Firefox Sync](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-set-sync-my-computer). Create an account, log into it from your Windows copy of Firefox, then connect your Linux copy of Firefox to it.

As a bonus, the bookmarks will stay in sync also in the future, if you are going to keep using both Windows and Linux at the same time.

Comment: You should explain how to configure Firefox Sync to prevent everything from 2-way syncing to everything on both devices which will make a mess out of IDK's Windows 8.1 bookmarks. Unless that's what you intended to say.

Comment: @karel Two-way syncing is what I intended to suggest. I don't know how to disable it, and I don't know if it is what OP wants.